# How to add QInputDialog.getText text inside a QGraphicsPolygonItem?

Tags: qt, pyqt4

I'm building in PyQt4 and can't figure out how to add text to a QGraphicsPolygonItem. The idea is to have text set in the middle of a rectangular box after a user double clicks (and gets a dialog box via QInputDialog.getText).

The class is:

```
class DiagramItem(QtGui.QGraphicsPolygonItem):
    def __init__(self, diagramType, contextMenu, parent=None, scene=None):
      super(DiagramItem, self).__init__(parent, scene)
      path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
      rect = self.outlineRect()
      path.addRoundRect(rect, self.roundness(rect.width()), self.roundness(rect.height()))
      self.myPolygon = path.toFillPolygon()
```

My double mouse click event looks like this, but updates nothing!

```
def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
    text, ok = QtGui.QInputDialog.getText(QtGui.QInputDialog(),'Create Region Title','Enter Region Name: ', \
QtGui.QLineEdit.Normal, 'region name')
    if ok:
        self.myText = str(text)
        pic = QtGui.QPicture()
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(pic)
        qp.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Arial', 40))
        qp.drawText(10,10,200,200, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, self.myText)
        qp.end()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are not doing it correctly. You are painting to a `QPicture` (`pic`) and throwing it away.

I'm assuming you want to paint *on* the `QGraphicsPolygonItem`. [`paint`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qgraphicsitem.html#paint) method of `QGraphicsItem` (and its derivatives) is responsible for painting the item. If you want to paint extra things with the item, you should override that method and do your painting there:

```py
class DiagramItem(QtGui.QGraphicsPolygonItem):
    def __init__(self, diagramType, contextMenu, parent=None, scene=None):
          super(DiagramItem, self).__init__(parent, scene)
          # your `init` stuff
          # ...

          # just initialize an empty string for self.myText
          self.myText = ''

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        text, ok = QtGui.QInputDialog.getText(QtGui.QInputDialog(),
                                                  'Create Region Title',
                                                  'Enter Region Name: ',
                                                  QtGui.QLineEdit.Normal, 
                                                  'region name')
        if ok:
            # you can leave it as QString
            # besides in Python 2, you'll have problems with unicode text if you use str()
            self.myText = text
            # force an update
            self.update()

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget):
        # paint the PolygonItem's own stuff
        super(DiagramItem, self).paint(painter, option, widget)

        # now paint your text
        painter.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Arial', 40))
        painter.drawText(10,10,200,200, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, self.myText)
```

Comment: Thanks, Avaris. I discovered this EVENTUALLY after reading through a few more examples. Thanks for summarizing the solution so nicely.